# SQL with LIKE doesn't return anything (SQLite)

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'm trying to filter the results using this SQL expression:

```
SELECT ModelName, ModelSvmData, TrainedFeatureInfo, TrainedClassesInfo 
FROM Models 
WHERE NOT ModelName LIKE '_%'
```

(Names having underscore are to be filtered actually)

Unfortunately there are no results.
The column `ModelName` does contain 2 rows `main` and `_main`

Any hint?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The underscore character is a wildcard in the LIKE clause for a match of any single character. If you want to look for the literal underscore, you need to escape it so it is not treated as a wildcard.

```
...WHERE ModelName NOT LIKE '\_%' ESCAPE '\'
```

Comment: This will not show any row as the query becomes `...WHERE ModelName NOT LIKE '%' ` after escaping `_`

Comment: @PrerakSola Thanks. I corrected my brain cramp on the syntax.

Comment: Oh, that's interesting! I wonder how did I get away with SQL without knowing it till now. Have to check for more special characters. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

This is the correct syntax:

```
SELECT ModelName, ModelSvmData, TrainedFeatureInfo, TrainedClassesInfo 
FROM Models 
WHERE ModelName NOT LIKE '\_%'`
```

You need to escape `_` using `\` as `_` itself is a wild card character.
You can see other examples [here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp)

Comment: Why should \ be an escape character?